# Como quitar las etiquetas de un texto en html pero mantener los atributos en el texto

Tags: php

Quiero quitar las etiquetas `html` pero mantener el formato que generan las etiquetas en el texto.

Estoy usando la función `strip_tags()` que me quita las etiquetas `html` pero no me deja el formato..

Por ejemplo tengo este texto en html:

```
<font color="#ff0000">ZONA 1</font>;
```

Me quita las etiquetas pero el texto **ZONA 1** no se mantiene con el color rojo `ff0000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El texto como tal no tiene formato, el formato se da especificándolo a través de algún marcado, por ejemplo, en html `<strong> hola </strong>` , la etiqueta  es la que da sentido semántico a un texto en negrita, el navegador  interpreta que el texto debe ir en negrita, por lo cual a la hora de renderizar dicho texto, escoge la tipografía y modificaciones correctas.

*No puedes eliminar etiquetas html sin perder formato*, puesto que son uno mismo. Mi consejo es que utilices un lenguaje de marcado distinto, el cuál deberás convertirlo a html (una especie de SandBox)

Por ejemplo aquí en stackoverflow, utilizan Markdown

Los enlaces se escriben como: `[texto](https://enlace)`
y se visualizan como: [texto](https://enlace)

Las cursivas se escriben como: `*cursiva*`
y se visualizan como: *cursiva*

Los títulos se escriben como: `#Título`

y se visualizan como:

## Título

En general, existen cientos de lenguajes destinados a dar formato al texto, algunos muy generales como [BBCode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), [Markdown](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), [rtf](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), [TeX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)

Comment: Muchas graciias por la informacion!! ya encontré la solución gracias a Dios :D estoy usando laravel y en vez de usar la expresion {{ }} tenia que usar esta {!! !!} y me muestra los formatos perfectamente bello sin las etiquetas html *-*